Visual Studio project template with relative paths in ProjectReference
I have a task to create a Visual Studio project template that will be used by some developers to make test projects for already existing .csproj files (for example, making a App.Framework.Test.csproj file for App.Framework.csproj). This template must by default include references to some other C# projects that are needed for test runs. The issue is that in the original .csproj file I'm basing my template on there is a  tag that uses a relative path:
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\AnotherProject\TestFramework\AnotherProject.TestFramework.csproj">
   <Project>{a93e036d-604a-4382-8f4c-c8f58b32be04}</Project>
   <Name>AnotherProject.TestFramework</Name>
   <Private>False</Private>
</ProjectReference>

Therefore, when new .csproj is created from this template in a location different than where the ORIGINAL .csproj file was located, the ProjectReference breaks, and the path specified in it isn't valid anymore. Is it possible to somehow make this template more universal, when loading these references won't be an operation that depends on the location in which the project is being created in?
Thanks.

I went to search some information, and just want to ask, have you tried anything?  It seems that you can consider using Visual Studio macros or methods based on template parameters to dynamically generate reference paths. Have u looked up these methods?
